# how to get Razor form to use route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a Razor form

```
using (Html.BeginForm("TermList", "Course", FormMethod.Get))
{

    <div style="text-align:right;display:inline-block; width:48%; margin-right:25px;">
             @Html.DropDownList( "id", (SelectList) ViewBag.schoolId)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Choose school" />
}
```

I expected this form to post to URI of:

```
http://localhost:56939/Course/TermList/764
```

instead the route looks like:

```
http://localhost:56939/Course/TermList?id=764
```

the route is not being used. I'd like to do away with the parameter

```
?id=764
```

Comment: I've just solved this problem with a simple redirect http://stackoverflow.com/a/18105353/360211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `?id=764` is appended to the URL is because you're using `FormMethod.Get`. Any values you are going to pass along with your form will be added in the querystring. You need to use `FormMethod.Post`.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("TermList", "Course", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ... Your form stuff here ...
}
```

This will result in a form action of `http://localhost:56939/Course/TermList/`

If you want to post to `http://localhost:56939/Course/TermList/764` you need to pass the `id` parameter in the `Html.BeginForm` statement:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("TermList", "Course", new { @id = 764 }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    ... Your form stuff here ...
}
```

Obviously instead of hard coding `764` just use whatever variable it is that stores that value.

Comment: why use post ? `http://localhost:56939/Course/TermList/764` can be achieved with a GET

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your point, but the value selected will come from a dropdown. The dropdown value won't be selected at render time.

Comment: @DaveA Do you want the route to be `http://localhost:56939/Course/TermList/` or `http://localhost:56939/Course/TermList/764`? If you want the first route, the first solution I posted should still work as long as the dropdown has the name `id`. For the second route, I can update my answer to show how to do it with the value rom the dropdown.

Comment: the 2nd. I'd like it to be restfull. So i want to use get over post and the url should appear http://localhost:56939/Course/TermList/764. That's what I expected to get. I would appreciate any help getting to that point. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any real way to do it through the `Html.BeginForm()` helper simply because the browser will always render it as a querystring. You would have to use jQuery to alter the URL after the HTML is rendered. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891603/html-beginform-loses-routevalues-with-formmethod-get and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574181/asp-net-mvc-rewritting-formmethod-get-querystring