# Passing another query string param with Html.BeginForm and FormMethod.Get

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

**BACKGROUND**

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC 5. I have a list of products and want to filter them by name. I have a created a small form that sits above the product list.

**CODE**

Here is the Razor form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Page", "Inventory", routeValues: new { showDeleted = false }, method: FormMethod.Get))
{
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Search.SearchTerm, new { @class = "form-label" })
        <div class="controls">
          @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Search.SearchTerm, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Search.SearchTerm, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right filter">Filter Results</button>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

And here is the controller method it is suppose to hit:

```
public ActionResult Page(SearchViewModel search, bool showDeleted, int page = 1)
{
  var viewModel = _productService.GetPagedProducts(search, showDeleted, page);
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

Submitting the filter with whatever search terms breaks the application and gives the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'showDeleted' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Page(Proj.ViewModels.Shared.SearchViewModel, Boolean, Int32)' in 'Proj.Controllers.InventoryController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

I know why it is failing, it is because the `showDeleted` I've set up is getting ignored and thrown away! But I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891603/html-beginform-loses-routevalues-with-formmethod-get

Comment: I think hidden field can help you, @Html.Hidden("showDeleted", false)

Comment: Thanks @lyz, I understand what to do now. :)

Comment: Create a specific route for that method - `url: "Inventory/Page/{showDeleted}` so that its added as a route value, not a query string and then you do not need a hidden input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will generate the correct form action url with the querystring for the `showDeleted` parameter

```
action="/Inventory/Page?showDeleted=False"
```

But since you are using **GET** as the form submit method, when the form is submitted, browser will read the input element values from the form and build a querystring and append it to the form action url. This will overwrite your existing querystrings you had there.

If you want to send this in querystring with `GET` as the form method, you should have an input element in the form with the same name

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Page", "Inventory", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Search.SearchTerm, 
                          new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <input type="hidden" name="showDeleted" value="false" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary filter">Filter Results</button>

}
```

Comment: Is that the only way? Why does my `routeValues` get ditched?

Comment: Because you are doing a form submit using GET which will overwrite the querystring items with the form input elements.